# Paypal SDK error when native App is present

Tags: android, paypal-rest-sdk

we have integrated the Android Paypal SDK into our App. Sandbox payments work without a problem so far. A client reports now that if the the native Paypal App for Android is installed an error occurs. In english the error would be something like "Requirement not authorized" (this probably sounds strange, but the german version sounds equally stange).

Is there a way to prevent the Android SDK from accessing the native App and completely use the inApp Library?

Cheers
Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jeff from PayPal.  This was a bug in an old version of the SDK and the integration with the PayPal app.  If you upgrade the version of the SDK, this error will go away, and the user will no longer see that message.